# I want to set up a alert in tradingview when Engulfing candles touches one Moving Average line

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to set up a alert in tradingview when Engulfing candles touches one Moving Average line. I created some part. But not able to define the touches of the enguling candles and moving average.

Here is my code:

```
`//@version=5
indicator(title="Indicator", shorttitle="In", overlay=true, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
len = input.int(21, minval=1, title="Length")
src = input(close, title="Source")
smma = 0.0
smma := na(smma[1]) ? ta.sma(src, len) : (smma[1] * (len - 1) + src) / len
openBarPrevious = open[1]
closeBarPrevious = close[1]
openBarCurrent = open
closeBarCurrent = close
green = color.green
red = color.red

//If current bar open is less than equal to the previous bar close AND current bar open is less than previous bar open AND current bar close is greater than previous bar open THEN True
bullishEngulfing = (openBarCurrent <= closeBarPrevious) and (openBarCurrent < openBarPrevious) and (closeBarCurrent > openBarPrevious)
//If current bar open is greater than equal to previous bar close AND current bar open is greater than previous bar open AND current bar close is less than previous bar open THEN True
bearishEngulfing = (openBarCurrent >= closeBarPrevious) and (openBarCurrent > openBarPrevious) and (closeBarCurrent < openBarPrevious)


//bullishEngulfing/bearishEngulfing return a value of 1 or 0; if 1 then plot on chart, if 0 then don't plot
plotshape(bullishEngulfing, style = shape.triangleup, location = location.belowbar, color = green, size = size.tiny)
plotshape(bearishEngulfing, style = shape.triangledown , location = location.abovebar, color = red, size = size.tiny)
plot(smma, color=#ffffff)`
```

I want to set an alert if Engulfing candles touches the Moving Average. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to detect a touch and not interested where the price is closed, you should use the wicks. Just check if the `high` or `low` of the candle crossed the MA line.

```
is_bullish_high_touch = bullishEngulfing and ta.cross(high, smma)
is_bearish_low_touch = bearishEngulfing and ta.cross(low, smma)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But was wondering if there is some way I can trigger the alert when the price (high or low) touches the MA. Also, is it possible to check whether the price is below the MA or above it.

Comment: Sure, it is possible. What have you tried? You can ask a new question for that.

Comment: Can you please check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75142796/pine-script-need-help-creating-tradingview-alerts-when-there-is-engulfing-candl