# Pine Script: Need help creating TradingView alerts when there is Engulfing candles and the price touch the MA

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, pine-script-v4

I want to set up a alert in tradingview when Engulfing candles touches one Moving Average line. I created some part. But not able to define the touches of the enguling candles and moving average.

Here is my code:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Indicator", shorttitle="Indi", overlay=true, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
len1 = input.int(21, minval=1, title="Length 21")
len2 = input.int(50, minval=1, title="Length 50")
len3 = input.int(200, minval=1, title="Length 200")
src = input(close, title="Source")
 
smma = 0.0
smma1 := na(smma[1]) ? ta.sma(src, len1) : (smma[1] * (len1 - 1) + src) / len1
smma2 := na(smma[1]) ? ta.sma(src, len2) : (smma[1] * (len2 - 1) + src) / len2
smma3 := na(smma[1]) ? ta.sma(src, len3) : (smma[1] * (len3 - 1) + src) / len3
openBarPrevious = open[1]
closeBarPrevious = close[1]
openBarCurrent = open
closeBarCurrent = close
green = color.green
red = color.red
 
//If current bar open is less than equal to the previous bar close AND current bar open is less than previous bar open AND current bar close is greater than previous bar open THEN True
bullishEngulfing = (openBarCurrent <= closeBarPrevious) and (openBarCurrent < openBarPrevious) and (closeBarCurrent > openBarPrevious)
//If current bar open is greater than equal to previous bar close AND current bar open is greater than previous bar open AND current bar close is less than previous bar open THEN True
bearishEngulfing = (openBarCurrent >= closeBarPrevious) and (openBarCurrent > openBarPrevious) and (closeBarCurrent < openBarPrevious)
 
 //bullishEngulfing/bearishEngulfing return a value of 1 or 0; if 1 then plot on chart, if 0 then don't plot
plotshape(bullishEngulfing, style = shape.triangleup, location = location.belowbar, color = green, size = size.tiny)
plotshape(bearishEngulfing, style = shape.triangledown , location = location.abovebar, color = red, size = size.tiny)
plot(smma1, color=#ffffff)
plot(smma2, color=#0000FF)
plot(smma3, color=#FF0000)
```

I want to set alerts based on thes Condition:

1. Long alerts when the price is on **top of smma3** (200 MA) and if **bullishEngulfing touches smma1**
2. Short alerts when the price is on **bottom of smma3** (200 MA) and if **bearishEngulfing touches smma1**

Example of the condition:

1. Long alert conditions are met here: https://prnt.sc/_m7glN3PEh_b (price/smma1 on top of smma2 and bullishEngulfing touches/crosses smma1
2. Short alert conditions are met here: https://prnt.sc/2FE6vKftTL-c (price/smma1 on bottom of smma2 and bearishEngulfing touches/crosses smma1

Answer (score 0):

To figure out if a candle touched some line, you should check if that line is in between the `high` and `low` of the candle.

For example,

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

sma_val = ta.sma(close, 100)
sma_touch = (sma_val <= high) and (sma_val >= low)

plot(sma_val)
plotshape(sma_touch)
```

[image]